# How to update the @ManyToMany mapping in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two relations in i.e `Relation_1` and `Relation_2` and In `relation_2` I have `@ManyToMany` property with `Relation_1`. I wanted to update primary key of `Relation_1` but because of foreign key constraint I got an error in sql query. What is the `CascadeType` should I set to support the Update Operation ?

```java
public class Relation_2 {
    @Id
    @column(name = "relation_2_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "relation_2_relation_1_mapping",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "relation_2_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "relation_1_id")}
    )
    private Set<Relation_1> relations;
}
```

```java
public class Relation_1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "relation_2_id", updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

I want to update the `id` in relation_1 and I want the `id` associated with `relation_2` changes automatically.

Comment: Why did you consider `updatable = false` for id in `Relation_1` ?

Comment: I can remove that but that'd not make any difference

Comment: You said that "In relation_2 I have @ManyToMany property with Relation_1" but the class Relation_2 has a ManyToMany on itself `private Set<Relation_2> relations;`, it should reference Relation_1

Comment: @StanislasKlukowski Yes thanks for pointing out. It was a typo

Comment: Try to specify `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` for id. Also you can set cascade to `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.